# LTS Auto upgrade to 14.04.1

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

When will auto upgrade to 14.04.1 be available from the software updater?
Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just doing an update? My PC is already updated.

Comment: @karel - I don't think that is a duplicate the question is asking about update from 12.04 to 14.04.1 not 14.04 to 14.04.1.  Update manager should start offering the update soon but I don't have an exact date.

Comment: This is guess work. It will arrive when it arrives.